# Code in user control breaks design mode in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I have a usercontrol that breaks design mode with a stack exception in Visual Studio 2015 when I modify pages the usercontrol is on. If I delete the bin folder/clean/recompile it briefly works again. The app itself runs fine. This code is conditionally called from the usercontrol_loaded or constructor

```
private async void GoBack()
{
    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        if (((Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as Page).GetType() == typeof(Inputs))
            return;

        if (((Frame)Window.Current.Content).CanGoBack)
        {
            foreach (PageStackEntry page in ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack)
            {
                if (page.SourcePageType != typeof(MainPage))
                    ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack.Remove(page);
            }
        }

        if (((Frame)Window.Current.Content).CanGoBack)
            ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).GoBack();
    });
}
```

And I get this error:

> at MainAppBar.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__3(Object
>   state)

Any suggestions on how to fix this? It designer seems to be running this code and is confused with the navigation code? Is there a way to exclude this code at design time?

Comment: As general advice, the designer will often break following changes that you make. It's better to learn not to rely on the designer and get in the habit of using code-behind, then you'll avoid this kind of issue altogether.

Comment: While I normally type in XAML directly, it's still nice to have the designer to visualize the layout. With this error, all the design shows me is a blank form and there was an exception. I can still make changes to the xaml, I just can't see anything I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's any particular code that cause problem at design mode, you can skip executing the method by checking if it's in Design mode.

```
    public static bool IsDesignMode(this object o)
    {
        return (bool) DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty, typeof (FrameworkElement)).Metadata.DefaultValue;
    }

    if (!this.IsDesignMode())
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(GoBack, ... 
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Skipping code on design time did fix it, I didn't mention it was a UWP app and the above code didn't work, used "public static bool isInDesignMode = Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled;"